# Squareup login Integration in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, square

I am implementing Squareup SDK in my app, but unable to get appropriate solution for integration.How can I get user information as there is no code given on developer.portal for login intergration.

On GitHub and developer portal, steps are only given for making `payment` ,no steps or code given for retrieve (customer/user) info.

Here is GitHub link: https://github.com/square/SquarePointOfSaleSDK-iOS

If anyone have idea to login integration in iOS ,please guide or give some reference link.

Thanks

Comment: did you look into the example? https://github.com/square/SquarePointOfSaleSDK-iOS/tree/master/Examples

Comment: @AqeelAhmad Yes, I have checked given examples, it is only for making payments, not for getting user credentials(login integration).

Comment: The POS SDK requires the user to login to the actual Square POS application (as it will hand over control to it). If the user is not logged in, it will fail and return to your application with an appropriate error. There's no way to log the user in directly via API.

Comment: okay, thanks @sjosey